# SQL - Subselect in select clause - how to create column which decides uniqity logic

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to write subselect which will run through returned data, then checks status of all and then decides uniquity logic.

Is there any way to find out following ?

- case any of data has 'Active' status first one will be marked as 1 everything else as 0
- case there is no 'Active' status then first 'Expired' status will by marked as 1 and everything else as 0
- case there is no 'Active' and 'Expired' status then first 'In Progress' will be marked as 1 and everything else as 0

I was trying to write it like this but i need to have it in one case statement

```
SELECT a.id, a.status,
,(SELECT 
    CASE WHEN b.STATUS = 'Active' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    CASE WHEN b.STATUS = 'Expired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM b.TABLE
    WHERE a.id=b.id )AS unique
FROM my.TABLE
```

Result should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCA74.png picture for expired case

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Comment: There's no the first or the last rows in database table, because database tables are sets of rows. To call some row the first or the last you need to order them by some criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id
                                     order by case status when 'Active' then 1 when 'Expired' then 2 else 3 end
                                    ) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as unique_flag
from my.table t;
```

Comment: Its not working for me .. the =1 after partition by id is getting unexpected token ")" But thanks for window function I think i will be able to look it up.

Comment: Thank you for update astentx. Order by case is not working in this situation it only returns 1. I am trying to figure out the right way

Comment: Okay it finally works .. your solution was perfect however in my case partition over ID was not good column to select (IDs were unique thats whyt rownum was returning 1 all the time)thats why it wasnt working.. thank you guys again.. I have learned a lot on this

Answer (score 0):

If the lookup table is the same as source table, then you can use `LAG` function with constant and use its default value to mark the first row with 1 and others with 0. But you need to order your rows by some fields to deal with duplicates on status.

```
select a.id, a.status,
  lag(0, 1, 1) over(
    partition by a.id
    order by 
      case a.status
        when 'Active' then 0
        when 'Expired' then 1
        else 3
      end asc,
      a.some_more_columns asc /*To find that first row when there are duplicates by status*/
  ) as unique_flag
from MY_TABLE a
```

And what about object naming: never use keywords as identifiers. Calling column with date as `date`, table with users as `users` and some unknown table as `table` makes you design error prone.

Comment: Thanks.. yes i dont use keywords as identifiers I was just changing it for the example.. but the select is more complicated it uses 5 tables and more filters.. So I am just trying to simplify it so i can understand how it works. :) thanks for answer

Comment: @PeterPotoma It does not matter how complex your query is, because you can wrap it with CTE (`with clause`) and refer to it as to general table. If you lookup into the same dataset as you have in input, then it will work. If no, then apply row numbering from the above query to your lookup dataset and then join it. If you need to filter that dataset on some data from source set, then use join and apply that row numbering on joined data. If no one is your case, so please clarify your requirement, because you cannot get multiple values in one column and one row in SQL by its design.